# using ContentProviders with one to many relationship

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-cursor

I was looking for information regarding one to many relations on SQLite and found out that creating a relationship is as easy as adding the following to the "many" table:

`FOREIGN KEY(foreign_key_name) REFERENCES one_table_name(primary_key_name)`

Now the relation is created, but how do i take advantage of it while using `ContentProvider` on Android?

Say I have a Parent with some Children, so one to many relationship. From what i've seen on various android sqlite examples people usually save the Parent, then using returned id stores all Children as using `ContentProvider` and `ContentValues` there is no way i can put a list of Children into `ContentValues` before saving the Parent. This goes same for `Cursor` implementation for fetching data from database as there is no `cursor.getList(...)` or similar.

Is there a way for me to take advantage of the defined one to many relationship and somehow save/fetch Parent together with Children on SQLite using `ContentProviders`?

Comment: Few modern Android apps need a `ContentProvider` for database content. Why are you creating one?

Comment: It's a requirement, other than that I'm really curious because Google and Android pushes ContentProviders to developers as the way to go, but it seems to have all these limitations.

Comment: Why is it a requirement? The purpose of a `ContentProvider` is to allow *other* apps to access the data.

Comment: "Google and Android pushes ContentProviders to developers as the way to go" -- they have not done so in years.

Comment: @CommonsWare well for eg. google has a nanodegree program for Android on udacity. I know for a fact that all the material (videos featuring android engineers) insist on using ContentProviders and it's a requirement on all the excercises. Anyways, my initial question here is not if i should use something, but how.